# Routing goes nuts on asp .net mvc 2 application that is the same app set up 2x on the same server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

This is going to sound quite bizarre. I have one ASP .NET MVC 2 application. Works great. Routing is not very complicated. I am running this on windows 2003 IIS 6, so I have to use the {controller}.aspx routing configuration.

Anyhow, I've set the same MVC 2 application up twice under different virtual directories on IIS. This is literally a copy/paste of the existing app files to the new directory. The virtual directory / app name is of course different for each.

Routing works perfect in the original application. In the second, I can't seem to get the login page to post to the login post action, let alone make it beyond that.

The most complicated url in my application is something akin to:

```
http://server:90/appName/controller.aspx/AnAction?StartPeriod=2008
```

My global.asax.cs looks like:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = "" }
        );
```

The application only has 2 controllers: Account & Mpa. Again, the exact same compiled code exists in both places on the same IIS server under different app names/virtual directories. Can anyone think of a reason I would get different behavior in the copied one (doesn't work/can't find views/throws 404's for just about everything beyond displaying the LogOn page of Account controller)?

**EDIT 1**

Another thing worth mentioning is that I'm using ValidateAntiForgeryToken attributes on all post methods in the Mpa.aspx controller. This is the controller that should be redirected to after the post to Account.aspx (which doesn't seem to really happen). I thought the issue was that the salt value used for the ValidateAntiForgeryToken  was the same for both applications since I copied & pasted. I've since changed the value for the original application, but I'm still getting the same results.

```
FYI: Here are the details returned from firebug. 

    **GET Account.aspx**
    http://server:90/MpaDemo/Account.aspx 200 OK 2.9 KB 15ms

    ParamsHeadersPostPutResponseCacheHTML
    Response Headersview source
    Date    Thu, 26 Aug 2010 20:42:57 GMT
    Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
    X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
    X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
    Set-Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=z1q43ezg2hvtx255i5y5df21; path=/; HttpOnly
    Cache-Control   private
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length  2921
    Request Headersview source
    Host    server:90
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive  115
    Connection  keep-alive
    Authorization   NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHoAAAAYABgAkgAAAAoACgBIAAAADgAOAFIAAAAaABoAYAAAAAAAAACqAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPdABtAGsAbgBiAGIAMAAwADUAagB4AGIATQBTAEoAQQBLAE0ATwBMADIANAAxADAAOADIJ4z3L+WAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhigoN+1bIPZirxXzNQHWNIu/rx4Senq8=


    **Account.aspx POST**

    Date    Thu, 26 Aug 2010 20:44:26 GMT
    Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
    X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
    X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
    Location    /MpaDemo/Mpa.aspx/CustomErrorView?aspxerrorpath=/MpaDemo/Account.aspx
    Cache-Control   private
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length  200
    Request Headersview source
    Host    SERVER:90
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive  115
    Connection  keep-alive
    Referer http://SERVER:90/MpaDemo/Account.aspx
    Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=z1q43ezg2hvtx255i5y5df21

    **GET CustomErrorView**

    Response Headersview source
    Date    Thu, 26 Aug 2010 20:44:26 GMT
    Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
    X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
    Cache-Control   private
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length  1534
    Request Headersview source
    Host    server:90
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive  115
    Connection  keep-alive
    Referer http://server:90/MpaDemo/Account.aspx
    Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=z1q43ezg2hvtx255i5y5df21
```

Comment: when you click login button where does it actually post to? Use Firebug in Firefox to find that out.

Comment: Hey @mare. Kicking myself for not thinking about this. Firebug says it posts to Account.aspx, as it should; however, a Get request is done immediately to my CustomErrorView, which is my defacto error page when something goes wrong. This page doesn't actually get displayed though. A 404 is the Status for this URL Get request. I have a line in my post action that should write to the log file, but that never happens, so it doesn't seem like the Post is actually completed. The status for the Post to Account.aspx is 302 Found.

Comment: Mind you on my other site where everything works, the Post status to Account.aspx is 200 OK.

Comment: This must be OS and IIS specific, very strange and it will be an overkill to debug unless someone already had this problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is annoying. I forgot to check permissions on the folders I copied. Apparently, attempting to write to the log & not being able to threw an error, which my try/catch block caught, but then in the catch, I try logging the error, which threw another one, which my general catch all page should have caught, but didn't because the web.config had it under another controller.

*sigh*

Long story short, I removed the controller requirement for the shared error page like so:

Was: `defaultRedirect="~/Mpa/CustomErrorView"` Is now: `defaultRedirect="~/CustomErrorView"`

The view for the error page is in the Shared directory of the Views folder.

Lastly, I added the correct permissions to my logging folder.

Now it all works.

Wow. This took me 6 hours to figure out. I feel really, really lame.

Comment: I understand how you feel but it happens. Every time it happens you discover that you really really need to start thinking out of the box, in an extreme sense of it, so maybe the next time it will happen you will be able to think of the most impossible option that might have something to do with your problem ;)

Comment: No kidding. Thanks for your help though. I got some use from firebug so that's going to be helpful going forward. This is a prime example of a situation where you know things should just work. I shouldn't have gone down the routing path...it never made any sense to begin with. Permissions would have been the prime candidate if I had just stepped back and thought about it without trying random things like a crazy person. Again, thanks for your help mare!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switch from IIS 6 to IIS Developer Express which should run on 2003 and support all the new MVC features.

Quote from ScottGu's site:

•It works on Windows XP and higher operating systems – giving you a full IIS 7.x developer feature-set on all OS platforms

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-iis-developer-express.aspx

[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but we can't really change IIS on the server as this application will go into production on a Windows 2003 / IIS 6 machine. IIS Dev Express is not intended for production use.

Comment: It's not ready for production yet but it might be in a few months or maybe even sooner, so it might be worth testing with it.